# How can I check the assignment of a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: winedt

In WinEdt (v8.1) when I press F9 I believe the macro PDFTeXify is run.

Is it possible to check this setting somewhere, e.g. to get an overview of all keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Which version of WinEdt do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Options` → `Options Interface`. Choose (single click) `Main Menu`. Click on the down arrow (circled in red). Click on `Shortcuts`. Now all the short cuts are copied to clip board. Open a new file and paste.

[image]

All the short cuts can be seen as in the screen shot.  I did this in version 8.1.

Comment: It works. Although I cannot verify from this information whether F9 and PDFTeXify are equal commands.

Answer (score 4):

Harish has already anwered your question, but the shortcut <kbd>F9</kbd> does not necessarily run the "PDFTeXify" command.

In fact, if you paste the shortcuts in a blank document as described in Harish's answer, you will probably see

```
F9                     &Accessories|HTML &Help Compiler
F9                     &Accessories|&Compile
F9                     &Accessories|Compile &NSIS Script
F9                     &Accessories|&Compile
```

This means that <kbd>F9</kbd> is a so called configuration-dependant shortcut.

If you go to Options -> Configurations menu you will see

[image]

As you can see, WinEdt can be used not only as a TeX editor, but also to edit NSIS scripts, HTML Help projects.

If you choose "NSIS Editor" from this menu, <kbd>F9</kbd> becomes a shortcut to "Compile NSIS Script".

Now, you surely won't bother about this, and you are probably using the "Default" configuration. In this case, <kbd>F9</kbd> is a shortcut to "Compile".

The "Compile" command is a so called mode-dependant command, which means that it does different things depending on the *mode* of your document.

The mode of your document can be seen in the status line at the bottom of the editor window. When editing TeX documents, you will see something like

[image]

which tells you that you are in "TeX" mode.

The command "Compile" runs MetaPost if you are in "MetaPost" mode, MetaFont if you are in "MetaFont" mode, and so on. When you are in "TeX" mode, it runs PDFTeXify, or TeXify, or TeXify+DVIPS depending on the "PDFTeXify Method" you have chosen in the "TeX Options" tab of the Execution Modes interface (Options menu):

[image]

Ultimately, <kbd>F9</kbd> runs "PDFTeXify" only if you are in a TeX-related configuration, and your document is in "TeX" mode, and you have chosen "PDFTeXify" as "PDFTeXify Method", which are probably the settings you are using.

BTW: the shortcut that runs (for sure) "PDFTeXify" is <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd>

Thanks for reading this answer :-)

Comment: As I doubted, F9 is the mode dependant compilation short cut. Am I right?

Comment: @HarishKumar It is configuration-dependant and mode-dependant.