# Auto-hide Winedt Console

Tags: pdftex, compiling, winedt

Is there anyway to make Winedt console invisible when you are writing the code, and when the compile starts the console shows the log and then disappears by itself? Also if there is an error it stays visible until the error is resolved?

I change the setting for pdflatex, but I am using windows console instead of winedt console. It works as I described above, except that you don't see anything if there is no error. This gives you an impression that it winedt freezes or taking more than normal as you don't see any activity when you start the compile. Here is a snapshot of the pdflatex setting:

[image]

I am wondering if there is anyway to make the compilation more like TeXStudio which just shows a just the compile command in the console, unless there is an error?

EDIT: It is funny! This is the issue:

Let's say we have a paragraph with the word "research" in it. Put a \ before the word research and compile. If you have this setting that has --quiet option and is pretty what I want (fast compilation without lot's of texts in the console if no error):

[image]

Ctrl+E does not get you to the real error that is \research no matter how many times you press Ctrl+E. But if you have this setting:

[image]

when you compile, it highlights \research with red color that is exactly true. Am I missing something here? or --quiet is doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9):

The option to keep the WinEdt Console hidden and to show it only during the compilation is "Pause / Do not hide the Window".

When it is selected, the Console is always visible. When it is unselected, it does what you want.

I think the correct configuration you are looking for is the one in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Is there anyway to disable logging? I think it would be faster to not write to log file which I barely use it.

Comment: @user114781 WinEdt can do nothing about it. It is pdflatex that generates the `.log` file.

Comment: @user114781 Anyway you can add the option `--quiet` in "Switches" so you don't have output stream in the Console.

Comment: This makes WinEdt pretty similar to TeXStudio IF there is no error! but in TeXStudio if there is an error it gives you information about the error, line number and other details, but enabling --quiet in WinEdt will disable them all no matter if there is an error or not! Is there anyway to get some info about the error as well?

Comment: @user114781 Uncheck "Open Error Dialog"

Comment: Unchecking "Open Error Dialog" option won't give any info about the error if you have --quiet option!

Comment: @user114781 I forgot to say to enable "Pause / Do not hide the Window". Then with Ctrl+E you can jump to the errors.

Comment: It doesn't work for me! Ctrl+E does not do anything!

Comment: @user114781 Maybe you have custom settings for Ctrl+E. See this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163815/27635 to check what Ctrl+E is associated with.

Comment: No, it actually works but without option --quiet. My question was that: how one can have quiet option enabled which makes the compile faster (pretty similar to TeXStudio), AND get some details about the errors if any (again similar to TeXStudio), any idea?

Comment: @user114781 It works for me. I don't know what to say.

Comment: please see below question with images!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by selecting "No interaction" as well as "WinEdt Console":
[image]

Comment: This is wrong...

Comment: Because of the background windows?

Comment: No, because "No interaction" has nothing to do with it. As I say in my answer, the option that manages this is "Pause / Do not hide the Window".